# QScroll area within QStackedLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtgui

I have a QMainWindow with a QStackedWidget as the central widget, and having been switching between layouts by changing the current widget of this central widget.

This has been working fine, but now I am trying to make one of these possible layouts scrollable and this is the result:

[image]

---

**Code for MainWindow class:**

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)        

    #-- On load open main menu
    self.showMenu()  

# Go to the menu screen
def showMenu(self):
    widget_menu = WidgetMain(self)
    widget_menu.btnConfigu.clicked.connect(self.showConfig)
    self.central_widget.addWidget(widget_menu)
    self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(widget_menu)
    self.resize(420,350)

# Go to the config screen
def showConfigu(self):
    widget_configu = WidgetOptions(self)
    self.central_widget.addWidget(widget_configu)
    self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(widget_configu)
```

**Code for WidgetOptions class:**

```
class WidgetOptions(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(WidgetOptions, self).__init__(parent)

    #Container Widget        
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    layoutRightContainer = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    for _ in range(11):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("test")
        layoutRightContainer.addWidget(btn)
    widget.setLayout(layoutRightContainer)   
    widget
    self.setFixedHeight(300)             

    #Scroll Area Properties
    scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scroll.setWidget(widget)        

    layoutMain = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    layoutMain.addWidget(widget)
```

I've tried numerous tweaks to the set sizes, and making different containers non-/resizable. What works outside of a StackedWidget doesn't seem to work within one. There also doesn't seem to be any questions on SO with such a situation.
        self.setLayout(layoutMain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making the WidgetOptions class itself an extension of QScrollArea rather than a QWidget containing the QScrollArea

**Code for WidgetOptions class:**

```
class WidgetOptions(QtGui.QScrollArea):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(WidgetOptions, self).__init__(parent)

    layoutLeft = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()                
    self.btnVariables = QtGui.QPushButton("Variables")
    self.btnGroups = QtGui.QPushButton("Groups")
    layoutLeft.addWidget(self.btnVariables)
    layoutLeft.addWidget(self.btnGroups)

    #Container Widget        
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    layoutRightContainer = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    for _ in range(11):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("test")
        layoutRightContainer.addWidget(btn)
    widget.setLayout(layoutRightContainer)   

    #Scroll Area Properties
    self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.setWidget(widget)        

    self.setWidget(widget)
```